# Howto trigger ajaxStart and ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to trigger the ajaxStart and ajaxStop events to get an is-loading message to appear but I'm quite confused about how to do this. As I understand these events are triggerd with each ajax event, but I'm still not sure what that exactly means. 
Does clicking on a href link or on a submit button triggers an ajax event as well ? It seems not because not one of the alerts in my code below appear when clicking on hyperlinks or buttons.
I just started out learning JQuery and there is probably something obvious that I'm missing.

Someone can explain how to make this work ?

I have this in my `<head>` tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this just before the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    alert('ajaxStart');
    $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    alert('ajaxStop');
    $('#ajaxBusy').hide(); 
});

</script>
```

**Edit:**
I want by clicking on a href link to make the loading popup appear thus triggering the ajaxStart event.
The link call's another page which takes quite some time to load and I would want to have the loading message appear in the mean time.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/long-loading-page.php">link</a>
```

How would I do this with an ajax event ?

Comment: `jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStart");`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the AJAX events fire *you have to start an AJAX request*.

That means `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.load`, etc.

Clicking a link or button won't do.  However you can register your own `click` handler for each `a` element so that it uses `$.load` to retrieve the requested URL and then updates the DOM with that new content.  This definitely doesn't count as "Beginner's jQuery", though.

A better solution might be for the *new* page to use `document.write` or similar to throw up the popup as the page loads and then remove it when it's done.

Comment: at the bottom of the start-post

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) events that are triggered whenever any AJAX requests are made. Have a read here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ jQuery has an excellent documentation.

When you click on a link or a submit button browser simply loads a new page without initiating any AJAX requests.